# RIFF header, but not a WAV Error in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Friends,
I have just started usng actionscript and Im using the WaveContainer.as file from the location 
**https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/source/browse/src/edu/mit/csail/wami/audio/WaveContainer.as?r=6804f729530892cb4f644b546f92c4f68fa402c8**

that plays the uploaded files also. However it doent support all WAVE files for WAVE files that are not PCM formatted , I get the error that

**1. FLASH:Not WAV:  RIFF header, but not a WAV. 
 2. FLASH: Not Au: Not an AU header**

Please guide on how the WaveContainer.as can be modified to handle above two errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at line number 94, since it has:

```
var waveFmtStr:String = header.readUTFBytes(8);       // "WAVEfmt "
                    if (waveFmtStr != "WAVEfmt ") 
                    {
                            return notWav("RIFF header, but not a WAV.");
                    }
```

you can change it by commenting return line like this:

```
// return notWav("RIFF header, but not a WAV.");
```

But somehow it is one of the ways to get something completely destroyed.

---

Generally, you should be looking for those error texts in your code, trying to understand why it is codded like this and what will happen if you change something.